# return Array Method Assignment;

Tags: java

I am trying to return an array method is it possible ??

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int size;
    int [] myArray = new int [size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        myArray[i]= returnArray(size)[i];
        System.out.println(myArray(i));
    }

}

private static int [] returnArray(int size){
    int arr = new int [size];
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
        arr[x]=x;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, it should include the `homework` tag.

Comment: Have you even tried to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

```
int arr = new int [size];
```

should be:

```
int[] arr = new int [size];
```

and:

```
int [] myArray = new int [size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
 myArray[i]= returnArray(size)[i];
 System.out.println(myArray(i));
}
```

can be:

```
int [] myArray = returnArray(size);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
 System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```